# SOAP based WebService Security

Tags: web-services, https, ws-security

I've created a Web Service for our clients and I secured it using a username token with PasswordDigest (with timestamp, nonce and encrypted password). One of the client uses a software that does not support PasswordDigest, only plain text username and password.

I feel somewhat uncomfortable with plain-text passwords in the SOAP-Header. But the whole traffic is being secured using HTTPS.

My question: Using HTTPS, is it still secure enough, even if I change the security requirements from PasswordDigest to PasswordText?

My requirements are:

- The client has to be authenticated with a user name, because I have to know which client is accessing the Web Service and
- Any man-in-the-middle must not see the plain text password in the SOAP header!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to look into the [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) extension to SOAP.

As for you question, I wouldn't be afraid of using clear-text password on HTTPS, but as @Anshu says, make sure your service does not respond on HTTP then! Also, be aware that it is technically possible and often seen that corporate proxies effectively performs MitM "attacks" on HTTPS traffic...

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HTTPS`, you might be able to do away the `PasswordDigest` and use `PasswordText`, but you need to make sure that you never support an *unsecured request*.